# Parse from FILE structure to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, parsing, popen

I'm trying to capture a system command on Windows with the following code, to return the output as a string.

```
std::string exec(char* cmd) {
    FILE* pipe = _popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe) return "ERROR";
    std::ifstream ifs(pipe);
    std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                         (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
    printf("%s", content);
    return content;
}
```

When I call the function like this:

```
char *command = "set";
std::string results = exec(command);
printf("%s", results);
getchar();
```

The output is just a few random bytes.

```
    ╝÷:ö°:
```

I was trying to get all the results appended in 1 long string.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I tried redirecting the stderr to output with the command but it also gives some random bytes.

Comment: Will that even compile? There are no [`std::ifstream` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) in the standard library which takes a `FILE` pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `printf()` which knows nothing about C++ `std::string` values, you need to print the C string representation of the `content`:

```
printf("%s", content.c_str());
```

The `printf()` function was told to expect that, but it wasn't what you passed to it.

Or, as others pointed out, you should use the native C++ I/O:

```
std::cout << content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Printf expects C string, `char*`.

Use

```
printf("%s",results.c_str());
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `printf`, use the C++ standard output stream instead:

```
std::cout << content << '\n';
```